# Calculating the time difference(in hours and minutes)

Tags: php

I need a difference between these two:

```
$time1 = strtotime('26:56:45');
$time2 = strtotime('8:21:15');
```

Where output would be `18:53:30`.

Comment: where is the code which you have tried??

Comment: How can it be possible to have an `hours = 26`

Answer (score 1):

> @Pervez just use date() function two change your date time format like
>   below try it

```
<?php
     $time1 = strtotime('26:56:45'); 
     $time2 = strtotime('8:21:15');
     $difference = date("H:i", ($time1 - $time2));
     echo $difference;
?>
```

Here you will get the difference as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer..

**Example**

```
$time1 = strtotime('23:56');  // 2012-12-06 23:56
$time2 = strtotime('00:21');  // 2012-12-06 00:21
echo ($time1 - $time2)/60;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("10:50:30");

$datetime2 = new DateTime("now");

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->h,":",$interval->i,":",$interval->s;
```